# How to load php file with JS code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Since I am new to JS coding and web designing, I have a following doubt:

I have one html page which has onclick function for form text area. If text area remains empty and user clicks submit, it should display message to enter entry and if entry is right one the corresponding file should get open. I have if/else condition in JS file, which is giving appropriate message while text area remains empty but not loading file which I am mentioning when entry is not empty.

Below is the html snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="drugform" action="#">
        <pre> Drug Name<input type="text" name="name1" value="" /></pre>
        </p>

        <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick='buttoncheck()' />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="if-else-button.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and JS code is:

```
function buttoncheck() {
    if (Boolean(document.drugform.name1.value)) {
        load(form1.php);
    } else {
        alert('Enter Drug name');
    }
}
```

How to load file with js code (mentioned in if condition)?

Comment: Do you write any custom function i.e own function like `function load(){}`. Where is `load()` function?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to load that form1.php file in existing file then you can use ajax for for reference go  [here.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Ajax)

and if you want to redirect to another page then you should use

```
window.location.href = "form1.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'form1.php';
window.location.href = url;
```

Instead of `load(form1.php)`, substitute the above code snippet!

EDIT:

If you want to load the file without actually redirecting to a new page, you can use jquery's `.load()`
Check more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: That will redirect though, I believe OP wants something like the jQuery `.load()` method

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
function buttoncheck() {
    if (document.drugform.name1.value != "") {  // check not empty condition
        load("form1.php"); // passing value to function with quotes
    } else {
        alert('Enter Drug name');
    }
}
```